# Notation for field access in Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, notation, pseudocode

While writing array index in an algorithm $a[i]\gets v$ is conventionally used. Is the notation $a_{i}\gets v$ also used ?

If the algorithm uses `struct` or equivalent, some notation is required for property access. In some occasions $p(s)$ is used where $p$ is the property. Using $s \rightarrow p$ messes up with the assignment arrow. Using $s_{p}$ looks like $p$ is an index and $p\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$. Should $s["p"]$ be used ? What is the convention to denote property access in algorithm ?

Is there any reference where I can check different notations of these two scenarios ?

Comment: Pseudocode is not a programming language. The exact notation doesn't matter as long as it's clear and concise. You might want to use dot notation for properties.

Comment: Yes I am asking about conventions and references. Writing something too unconventional makes things hard to read.

Comment: $a[i]$ and $a_i$ are commonly used. Dot notation is commonly used. C-style $s \rightarrow p$ is not, in my experience.

Answer (score 3):

Not everyone follows the same conventions, but I'll describe the ones I see most commonly.  Your experience may vary.

- If $a$ is an array, $a[i]$ is typically used, but not $a_i$.
- If $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ is a sequence, $a_i$ is typically used, but not $a[i]$.  Usually sequences are not updateable.
- If $a$ is a string, you might see either $a[i]$ or $a_i$; both are common, in my experience.
- I have most commonly seen $s.p$ used for property access.  Sometimes I have seen people use $p(s)$ used.

Different sources may follow different conventions.  There is no one right answer.  A good approach is to find a textbook that you like (e.g., CLRS), and then follow the same conventions they use.  Odds are that they have put some thought into choosing consistent and understandable conventions, so they probably have chosen something reasonable.